How to prove opposite angle bisector theorem for convex quadrilaterals?
Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral with $BL$ and $DL$ be its angle bisectors. I want to know how to prove that the acute angle $\alpha$ between these bisectors is equal to $\frac{\left|\angle A - \angle C\right|}{2}$.
I've figured out there are three possible cases. The case when the bisectors intersect inside the quadrilateral, as shown here:

The case when the bisectors insersect outside the quadrilateral, as shown here:

...and the case when they are parallel, but the theorem holds even for that case.

Did you mean $\dfrac{\left|\angle B - \angle D\right|}{2}$ instead of $\dfrac{\left|\angle B - \angle C\right|}{2}$ ?

@Euclid Sorry for the typo, just got fixed. I meant $\frac{|\angle A - \angle C|}{2}$

Let point $E$ on $AD$ intersection of  $AD$ and extension of $BL$ .
$\angle BED = \angle A + \frac{\angle B}{2}$(exterior $\angle$ of $\triangle$)
$\alpha + \angle A + \frac{\angle B}{2} + \frac{\angle D}{2} = 180^{\circ}$ (in $\triangle BED$)
Since $\angle A + \angle B + \angle C +\angle D = 360^{\circ} $ then $ \frac{\angle A}{2} + \frac{\angle B}{2} + \frac{\angle C}{2} + \frac{\angle D}{2} = 180^{\circ}$
and
$\alpha + \angle A + \frac{\angle B}{2} + \frac{\angle D}{2} = \frac{\angle A}{2} + \frac{\angle B}{2} + \frac{\angle C}{2} + \frac{\angle D}{2}$
$\alpha  =  |\frac{\angle A}{2} - \frac{\angle C}{2}| $


Regardless of where the bisectors of $\widehat B$ and $\widehat D$ intersect, let them meet $AC$ at $E$ and $F$ respectively. The angle you are looking for is $|\widehat{LEA} - \widehat{LFA}|$. We have:
$$\widehat{LEA} = 180^o - \widehat{BAE} - \frac{\widehat B}{2}$$
$$\widehat{LFA} = \widehat{FAD} + \frac{\widehat D}{2}$$
And you can take it from here.

In your first figure:
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &=\pi-\angle BLD\\
&=\pi-(2\pi-\angle B/2-\angle D/2-\angle C)\\
&={\angle B+\angle D\over2}+\angle C-\pi\\
&={2\pi-\angle A-\angle C\over2}+\angle C-\pi\\
&={\angle C-\angle A\over2}\\
\end{align}
$$
The other cases can be dealt with in a similar way.

So there is no way to avoid case analysis in this problem?
